# Connection problem and script broke when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Have problem with connection maybe its fault from my internet but what I can do?

I create module for scraping pages.

like:

```
def scrape(page):
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect=5, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    url = page
    
    result = session.get(url)
   

    # result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        #soup dla całej treści, bez opisu. on jest ładowany osobno w soup2 z faktu, że jest wczytywany przez js
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
```

and in second script i send url's adress from csv file its like 8000 links

and sometimes my script broke and send communicate like this:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Próba połączenia nie powiodła się, ponieważ połączona strona nie odpowiedziała poprawnie po ustalonym okresie czasu lub utworzone połączenie nie powiodło się, ponieważ połączony host nie odpowiedział

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000242E2F1CE80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Próba połączenia nie powiodła się, ponieważ połączona strona nie odpowiedziała poprawnie po ustalonym okresie czasu lub utworzone połączenie nie powiodło się, ponieważ połączony host nie odpowiedział

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gorabbit.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dep-551-1153lr-ld-em-001.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000242E2F1CE80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Próba połączenia nie powiodła się, ponieważ połączona strona nie odpowiedziała poprawnie po ustalonym okresie czasu lub utworzone połączenie nie powiodło się, ponieważ połączony host nie odpowiedział',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Nomax/Rabit/GorabitToCSV.py", line 217, in <module>
    map = read_csv(plik_wsadowy)
  File "E:/Nomax/Rabit/GorabitToCSV.py", line 176, in read_csv
    object_rabit = scrape(row[1])
  File "E:\Nomax\Rabit\scraping_module.py", line 24, in scrape
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gorabbit.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dep-551-1153lr-ld-em-001.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000242E2F1CE80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Próba połączenia nie powiodła się, ponieważ połączona strona nie odpowiedziała poprawnie po ustalonym okresie czasu lub utworzone połączenie nie powiodło się, ponieważ połączony host nie odpowiedział',))
```

How i can avoid it. I change normal requests to session but some times its fail too.

Like some times error show in 6000 url sometimes when its only 400 pages

Comment: did you try using TRY/EXEPT to solve this ?

Comment: **typo, I meant except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is unclear to me from your description just how relyable your connection really is, so let's jost go for a very general solusion:

```
def scrape(page):
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=5, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        url = page
    
        result = session.get(url)
   

        # result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
       
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    except:
        print("probably connection error...")
```

if you wnt to try again and again just do:

```
def scrape_env(page):
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect=5, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    url = page
    
    result = session.get(url)
   

    # result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if result.status_code == 200:
       
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

def scrape(page, num_of_tries):
    try:
        scrape_env(page)
    except:
        if num_of_tries !=0:
           print("probably connection error... try number ", num_of_tries)
           num_of_tries -=1
           scrape(page, num_of_tries)
        else:
           print("could not scrape, sorry")
```

Comment: I try some like this but i need keep trying until successful connection

Comment: ok, so pun it in  the except scope! here, I am editing my answer now for you